# Tried to implement Leetcode's FizzBuzz multithreading question from scratch. Getting "libc++abi.dylib: terminating" error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I started learning multithreading a few days ago because of a coming internship interview. I learned it and tried to solve Leetcode's FizzBuzz multithreading question which I could solve successfully. But then I remembered that in the first interview I was asked to code from scratch and so I tried to implement the problem. I searched the error online but couldn't figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class FizzBuzz
{
private:
    int n;
    int currentNum;
    std::mutex mu;
    std::condition_variable cond;
public:
    FizzBuzz(int n)
    {
        this->n = n;
        currentNum = 1;
    }

    void fizz();
    void buzz();
    void fizzbuzz();
    void number();
};

void FizzBuzz::fizz()
{
    while(currentNum <= n)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        if (currentNum%3==0 && currentNum%5!=0)
        {
            std::cout << "Fizz" <<std::endl;
            currentNum++;
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            cond.wait(locker);
        }
    }
}

void FizzBuzz::buzz()
{
    while(currentNum <= n)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        if (currentNum%3!=0 && currentNum%5==0)
        {
            std::cout << "Buzz" <<std::endl;
            currentNum++;
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            cond.wait(locker);
        }
    }
}

void FizzBuzz::fizzbuzz()
{
    while(currentNum <= n)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        if (currentNum%3==0 && currentNum%5==0)
        {
            std::cout << "FizzBuzz" <<std::endl;
            currentNum++;
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            cond.wait(locker);
        }
    }
}

void FizzBuzz::number()
{
    while(currentNum <= n)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        if (currentNum%3==0 && currentNum%5!=0)
        {
            std::cout << currentNum <<std::endl;
            currentNum++;
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            cond.wait(locker);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    FizzBuzz fb(15);
    std::thread t1 (&FizzBuzz::fizz, &fb);
    std::thread t2 (&FizzBuzz::buzz, &fb);
    std::thread t3 (&FizzBuzz::fizzbuzz, &fb);
    std::thread t4 (&FizzBuzz::number, &fb);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If you have other tips for me to improve myself, let me know. I'm new to multithreading. Trying to learn as much as possible.


EDIT: Added the join() statements for all the threads. Now it's getting into a deadlock.

Comment: Already answered by Anthony (join the threads), but apart from this, you should always `cv::wait` with the predicate to avoid spurious wakeups and missed notifications.

Comment: @pptaszni I joined the threads but they are going into a deadlock. And about the predicate, I didn't use it here because I thought even if there is a spurious wakeup, it'll have to again go through the if condition first.

Answer (score 1):

In your `FizzBuzz::number()` the first if condition should be:
`"if (currentNum%3!=0 && currentNum%5!=0)"`
not
`"if (currentNum%3==0 && currentNum%5!=0)"`

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `join()` on any of your threads. This will cause the application to terminate when the `std::thread` objects are destroyed.

Add

```
t4.join();
t3.join();
t2.join();
t1.join();
```

to the end of your `main` function. This will wait until the threads finish before exiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when `currentNum = 1` (your first value): `currentNum % 3 == 0` and `currentNum % 5 == 0` are both false. All threads end up waiting forever.

You should add this condition to some thread:

```
if (currentNum % 3 != 0 && currentNum % 5 != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition for the function printing number

```
if (currentNum % 3 != 0 && currentNum % 5 != 0) {
 ...
}
```

it works